# Изменить значение WebRTC | Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, webrtc

Хочу написать что то на подобии антидетект браузера на Selenium, и вот поставил прокси, захожу на сайт pixelscan.com
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И тут видно мой настоящий IP.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddHttpProxy("154.30.133.140", 8000, "NHG3YB", "aTzbHd");
        driver = new ChromeDriver("E:\\chrome",options);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://2ip.ru/");
    }
```

Каким образом можно изменить RTC адрес, на такой как и в прокси?

Comment: Селениум - это инструмент для автоматического тестирования своего сайта, автоматизации процессов администрирования, он не предназначен для того, чтобы делать на нем ботов и тем более для того, чтобы делать "антидетект браузер". Хотите свой браузер, берите исходники хрома (Chromium), на C# это CefSharp, и вот уже на основе этих исходников делайте свой собственный браузер, выпиливая/переписывая там весь функционал.

Comment: Прокся должна быть анонимной.